# Find the indices of the k smallest values in C

Tags: c, matrix, knn

I'm implementing K Nearest Neighbor in C and I've gotten to the point where I've computed a distance matrix of every point in my to-be-labeled set of size m to every point in my already-labeled set of size n. The format of this matrix is

```
[[dist_0,0 ... dist_0,n-1]
 .
 .
 . 
 [dist_m-1,0 ... dist_m-1,n-1]]
```

Next, I need to find the k smallest distances in each row so I can use the column indices to access the labels of those points and then compute the label for the point the row index is referring to. The latter part is trivial but computing the indices of the k smallest distances has me stumped. Python has easy ways to do something like this but the bare bones nature of C has gotten me a bit frustrated. I'd appreciate some pointers (no pun intended) on what to go about doing and any helpful functions C might have to help.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing `k`, and assuming that it can be variable, the simplest way to do this would be to:

1. Organize each element in a structure which holds the original column index.
2. Sort each row of the matrix in ascending order and take the first `k` elements of that row.

---

```
struct item {
    unsigned value;
    size_t index;
};

int compare_items(void *a, void *b) {
    struct item *item_a = a;
    struct item *item_b = b;

    if (item_a->value < item_b->value)
        return -1;
    if (item_a->value > item_b->value)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

// Your matrix:
struct item matrix[N][M];

/* Populate the matrix... make sure that each index is set,
 * e.g. matrix[0][0] has index = 0.
 */

size_t i, j;

for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    qsort(matrix[i], N, sizeof(struct item), compare_items);

    /* Now the i-th row is sorted and you can take a look
     * at the first k elements of the row.
     */
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        // Do something with matrix[i][j].index ...
    }
}
```